# Is there a "theory" of operating systems?

Tags: operating-systems, theory

Is there a theory for Operating Systems?

That is, subfields of CS have theoretical parts; i.e. PL has type theory, ML has mathematical theorems, security has a lot of provable properties, etc.

There are certain "properties" in OS, like the optimality of SJF scheduling algorithm or the dining philosophers, but these seem like small examples.

I feel like most of OS is engineering -- i.e. paging mechanisms, scheduling algorithms, thread management. Is there a "foundational theory" of Operating Systems?